# Is it possible to send Logs/Traces to datadog directly?

Tags: datadog

Im having a hard time figuring out a very simple scenario: send a simple log directly to datadog

You see, all samples and SDKs assume that you have a sidecar or a agent or something on your local machine or pod or etc, and your supposed to send that data to that agent so that the agent uploads it to datadog...

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an API endpoint to send logs if you'd like:

https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/logs/#send-logs